# If I call Firebase's getToken right after requestPermission I get an error in the console, why?

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

If I call Firebase's getToken right after requestPermission I get an error in the console *most of the time*. This is my current code:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script>
var config = {
apiKey: "XXXXXXXXX",
authDomain: "XXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://XXXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "XXXXXXXXX",
storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXX.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXX"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
<script>
function notification_permission() {
    messaging.requestPermission().then(function(permission) {
        console.log('Notification permission granted', permission);
        messaging.getToken().then(function(token) {
            if(token) {
                //update user token
                console.log('Token acquired', token);
            } else {
                //you don't have permission to show notifications
            }
        }).catch(function(err) {
            //retrieving token failed, analyze the error
            console.error('Retrieving token failed', err);
        });
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error('Unable to get permission to notify', err)
    });
}
</script>
```

If the browser already has notification permissions and I call `notification_permission();`, then I receive the **token** without any issues in the console. But if it is the first time that user presses **Allow** to give the site permissions to receive notifications, then this error is triggered (not always but most of the time):

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/connect/subscribe 404 ()

Retrieving token failed e {code: "messaging/token-subscribe-failed", message: "Requested entity was not found.", stack: "FirebaseError: Requested entity was not found."}
Promise.catch (async)
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ VM1243:1
```

Any ideas why? Thanks!

Comment: Getting this issue as well, have filed a support request, will let you know what they say.

You can get token if you call `messaging.getToken()` in the catch though :/

Comment: @RobertDaly great tip, in the meantime i'll guess i'll have a plan B to get the token value in the catch. Can you share the link of the support request so I can follow up the response? Thanks!

Comment: They gave me a generic answer saying I need to link an app, even though the call works the second time it's called. Not having this issue in 4.13.0 as below though!

Comment: @RobertDaly yes, the new version avoids this issue completely!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the latest version (4.13.0).  I see a fix for this in the release notes and it seems to work ok for me now.
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'm testing the new version right now.

Comment: Yes, this issue is fixed with 4.13.0.
I confirmed with `Version 5.8.5` (Release Date: Mar 1, 2019)